# Forced Out at Third Base

Tags: baseball, softball

There’s a runner on first. The batter hits a ball to left field. Runner on first advances to second, hitter decides to round first and advance to second as well forcing runner on second to now advance to third. The play is made at third by tagging the base not the runner. Is this considered an out, or is the runner safe even though the hitter now occupies second base?

Comment: Note that the runner at 2nd is not forced (by rule) to try to advance to 3rd just because the batter/runner decides to run from 1st to 2nd.

Answer (score 4):

The runner would not be out unless tagged while not on a base.  A force at third only exists if there are two runners behind him.  Since there is an open base at first, there is no force.

Comment: You are partly wrong.  The runner would be out if tagged while on 3rd.  The leading runner has the right to the base.

Comment: You are making no sense.  If there is only one runner behind the runner at third, it doesn't matter where the runner behind him is.  If the leading runner is standing on third he cannot be tagged out.  100%.  If you think I'm wrong find the rule in the rule book..

Answer (score 0):

It's not a force out situation.  You must tag the middle runner before he gets back to 2nd.

The middle runner has only one safe base to get to and that's 2nd even if 2nd is occupied.

If the middle runner gets back to 2nd then the first runner's only option is 1st.

[Two runners on the same base](http://www.qcbaseball.com/rules/base-runner-two-runners-occupying-a-base.aspx)

Comment: What middle runner? The situation only states a runner who started on first and the batter who became a runner.